# Broken confidence interval areas when using ylim in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been using `ggplot2` for long, but never experienced this issue. I am representing confidence intervals of some regressions. However, I decided to manually control the `ylim()`. I realized that those areas which exceed the y limits are broken. See this picture:

[image]

The red regression on the right contains a very wide CLs. As you can see there is a gap in there as its highest point is outside ylim range.

This is the code I used:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=Species, colour=Species, linetype = Species)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", formula= y~poly(x,3), level=0.95, alpha=0.2) + 
  xlab("A") +
  ylab("B") + 
  ylim(0, 30) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, size = 10),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position='bottom',
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour="azure2"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", 
                      size = 0.15, linetype = "solid")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1, 10, 1), limits=c(1, 10)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("coral4", "coral1", "darkolivegreen3", "darkgoldenrod4", "darkgoldenrod2", "deepskyblue3", "darkorchid3")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("coral4", "coral1", "darkolivegreen3", "darkgoldenrod4", "darkgoldenrod2", "deepskyblue3", "darkorchid3")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,1,1,3,3,2,2))
```

I would like to keep these y limits. I used `coord_cartesian` with no success. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

`coord_cartesian` should work, but you have to remove the `ylim()`

Some data

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data_frame(x = -5:5, y = rnorm(11, x^2, 5))
```

Replicating your problem

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
geom_smooth() +
ylim(-1, NA)
```

With `coord_cartesian`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
geom_smooth() +
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1, 40))
```

Comment: Thanks. I solved it by modifying your code with `  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 30), expand = c(-100, 100))`

Comment: The reason this happens is that `ylim()` and `xlim()` actually change your data before plotting, simply replacing the outside points with NA, while inside `coord_cartesian(...)` they merely define the part you see of your plot (Just in case someone cares ;) ).